# Laravel 5 Product Quantity reduce for every sale

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have an Laravel store with Product Quantity in my DB.

The Quantity left what Members see :

```
Quantity : {{$product->instock}}
```

Product Create :

```
<input type="number" name="instock" id="instock" class="productcreate" value="{{old('instock')}}" placeholder="Enter Your Quantity"> in Stock
```

Controller:

```
  if ($request->instock == null) {
    session()->flash('errormessage','Quantity is required');
    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
  }
```

How can I reduce my Quantity for every Sold item? Example I have 90 Items right now in stock. An Member buy one Item and the Quantity Reduce to 89 Items right now in  `Quantity: {{$product->instock}}`

What code must I add in my Controller for it?

Thanks

Comment: when order is successfully placed then you can reduce quantity from database `$product->instock = $product->instock - ($enteredquanity); $product->save()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When someone makes a purchase use the [`decrement()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#increment-and-decrement) method. Something like:

```
Product::decrement('instock', $itemsPurchased);
```